# individual input option for different options in select box html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am making a Radio button option. The user will select one of them and I need there to be individual upload option shown for any option selected. i.e when a user selects 'National ID', there will be an upload button to upload his NID's image that  will specifically say "Upload your NID image", and if he selects Passport, there will be an upload button shown which will take Passport image that  will specifically say "Upload your passport image".

```
<li id="li_6" >
<label class="description" for="element_6">Type of ID<strong><abbr 
title="Mandatory">*</abbr></strong></label>

<span>
<input id="element_6_1" name="element_6" class="element radio" type="radio" 
value="1" />

<label class="choice" for="element_6_1">NID</label>
<input id="element_6_2" name="element_6" class="element radio" 
type="radio" value="2" />
<label class="choice" for="element_6_2">Passport</label>

</span> </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

A classic implementation with vanillaJS might look like

[this](https://jsfiddle.net/w5qh17vg/).

Instead of defining `EventListeners` on each input element, you could leverage *event delegation* where the events from child elements bubble up to the parent on which you add a listener. This listener listenes, e.g. to the `change` event and sets the button text accordingly.

Which text is displayed is stored in the [data-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

The example above should be a good starting point for further implementation details.

Comment: But this example does not upload any file.